# Eclipse IDE calls out onclick attribute error in HTML file

Tags: javascript, eclipse

A project I imported into my Eclipse IDE has an HTML file with the following near the top of the file:

```
<div class="header_logo"><a href="./"   onclick=    javascript: return changePage(0, ''); class="logo"><img     src="images/logo-big.jpg" alt="Noridian" width="169" height="80" /></a></div>
```

The Eclipse IDE calls out the onclick as being in error:
***Open quote is expected for attribute "onclick" associated with an  element type  "a"***.

May I assume that the onclick should read:

```
<div class="header_logo"><a href="./"   onclick= "javascript: return changePage(0, '');" class="logo"><img  src="images/logo-big.jpg" alt="Noridian" width="169" height="80" /></a></div>
```

I am definitely not a Javascript expert but from what I have read, the statement following the onclick= should be surrounded with open quotes.

Comment: There is no reason to use `javascript:`. Your first line shows no quotes and your second one does.... so do you actually have quotes? `onclick="return changePage(0, '');"`

Comment: @epascarello `return` doesn't make sense here, does it?

Comment: @howlger makes perfect sense if you want to cancel the action

Comment: @epascarello I see. I didn't know that. Thank you for telling me that.

Comment: epascarello ...Correct ...the first line without quotes causes the warning message "Open quote is expected for attribute "onclick" associated with an element type "a". " ...when I then use quotes ( "javascript: return changePage(0, '');" ) ...the warning goes away ...I am just wondering if the quotes are indeed optional and the warning message is therefore erroneous.

Comment: Why would you think they're optional in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML the [**unquoted attribute value syntax**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-html53-20181018/syntax.html#elements-attributes) is only allowed for values without spaces, single quotes, etc.:

> The attribute name, followed by zero or more space characters,
> followed by a single U+003D EQUALS SIGN character, followed by zero or
> more space characters, followed by the attribute value, which, in
> addition to the requirements given above for attribute values, must
> not contain any literal space characters, any U+0022 QUOTATION MARK
> characters ("), U+0027 APOSTROPHE characters ('), U+003D EQUALS SIGN
> characters (=), U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN characters (<), U+003E
> GREATER-THAN SIGN characters (>), or U+0060 GRAVE ACCENT characters
> (`), and must not be the empty string.

So yes, the error is shown correctly, as this is not valid HTML without the quotes.